# Off topic comments growing on my answer

Tags: discussion, support, answers, comments

I've [answered a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/167913/9936) about plural "staff" which has attracted comments solely about plural "water". None has mentioned "staff" (the topic of the OP's question) or has suggested improvements.

I'm happy to edit my question if need be, however, if anyone is confused about plural "water", they should ask a question instead of discussing it in comments.

Would someone please delete all the comments and put up a message to discuss it in chat, or ask a new question (either one or both)?

Comment: Have you flagged the comments?

Comment: @Catija Yes, but just the first one.

Comment: My gratitude for giving a great answer to my question. However, I see those comments as relevant. It's different people using different ways to "make cuts", so to speak. You make the distinction between countable collective nouns and mass nouns, while some others make their cut by connecting water and staff in grammatical terms.

Comment: @Deansue The quantity of comments seem to indicate that the answer could be better, yet everyone seems to be discussing "water" instead of making suggestions for improvement. It's the classification of individual words that drives grammar, except in idioms which are usually ungrammatical in some way. I would say that I am also talking about grammar, but coming from a different angle. By the way, could you explain which usage of water you meant by "two waters"?

Comment: The examples of "waters" are unnecessary as they fail to actually explain what is wrong with the answer... it'd be useful if you edited your answer to say that even uncountable words can *sometimes* be used in plural countable ways - you only show a singular.

Comment: @Catija Are you talking about the informal _a water_?

Comment: @CJDennis I meant "water" as in _I'd like two waters please._ I agree some comments have gone astray. There is something I was hoping you could clarify. I will comment under your answer.

Comment: Both of the examples in the comments are *valid* uses of "waters" plural... and they're not informal. https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/waters

Comment: @Catija That's what I wondered about. I wasn't sure if _a water_ could be written off as informal...

Comment: @Catija, Deansue, It completely depends on the definition. Deansue, your definition only works informally. Catija, there are other definitions (out of at least ten) that are _only_ plural.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why you think that's not a valid thing to mention in your answer. The question is about plural usage, not singular, so talking about when water can be used in a singular form is... sort of irrelevant.

Comment: @Catija I'm not saying that at all. What I'm saying is that people are saying that if you can have _the waters of Finland_, then _water_ can always be used in the plural. Since the OP was asking about two drinks of water, these additional meanings are irrelevant, although potentially interesting in a different question. I stand by what I've said, but not necessarily how I've said it, which is why I'm prepared to improve the answer if I'm convinced my point can be made clearer.

Comment: Then that's something that @Deansue needs to clarify in the question... "Two waters" is all that the question says, which is ambiguous as to which version of "waters" is being mentioned. If Deansue means "I'd like two waters", the question should have the full sentence to make it clear why your answer goes that way.

Comment: @Catija Question edited. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There's no further meta to raise a question that even on OP's meta question, the number of comments are growing as well! :P

Comment: @MaulikV I can't ask about that on Meta.SE?